# how to display two arraylist in one iterator looping?

Tags: java, arraylist

i have two arraylist but how can i display both values in one iterator looping ? appreciated for helps.

### Example

```
ArrayList alRateCode      = new ArrayList();  
ArrayList alRateCode2     = new ArrayList();    
ArrayList alInner         = new ArrayList();
ArrayList alInner2        = new ArrayList();

alInner.add("A");
alInner.add("Apple");
alInner.add("1KG");
alInner.add("24.00");
alRateCode.add(alInner);

alInner2.add("B");
alInner2.add("Banana");
alInner2.add("1KG");
alInner2.add("10.00");
alRateCode2.add(alInner2);


for(Iterator i = alRateCode.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
{
        ArrayList alInner   = (ArrayList) i.next();
        String Code = (String) alInner.get(0);  // apple details
        String DESCP= (String) alInner.get(1);

        // how to loop banana details in this iterator
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Please use generics instead of raw lists: `ArrayList<String> alInner` and `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> alRateCode`. Eliminates need for casting and makes code more type-safe. (and documents list content type)

Answer (score 1):

```
Iterator i = alRateCode.iterator();
Iterator i2 = alRateCode2.iterator()

while(i.hasNext() && i2.hasNext()) {
   ArrayList appleInner   = (ArrayList) i.next();
   ArrayList bananaInner   = (ArrayList) i2.next();

   //Other code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have the answer in your question:

In your for loop intialize some variable with initial index and get value from `alRateCode2`

```
 for(int j=0,Iterator i = alRateCode.iterator(); i.hasNext();j++)
 {
    ArrayList alInner   = (ArrayList) i.next();
    String Code = (String) alInner.get(0);  // apple details
    String DESCP= (String) alInner.get(1);

    // how to loop banana details in this iterator
    ArrayList blInner   = (ArrayList) alRateCode2.get(j);
    String code1 = (String) blInner.get(0);  // banana details
    String DESCP2= (String) blInner.get(1);
}
```

Comment: Code would be better if you used `get(int index)` (not `getAt()`) for both lists.

Comment: failed to apply this way. Syntax error on token "i"

Comment: Well I have updated my answer to use get and also it's another variable j and not I

Comment: Hmm @VinayPrajapati i hit error syntax error on token "i"

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a method where you can pass 1-n arraylists as parameter and loop through it:

```
public static <T> void loopThroughArrayLists(ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>... lists) {
  for (ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> list : lists) {
    for (ArrayList<T> elements : list) {
      String Code = (String)elements.get(0); 
      String DESCP = (String)elements.get(1);
    }
  }
}

//usage
loopThroughArrayLists(alRateCode, alRateCode2);
```

But in my opinion, you should create a class for your "lower" arraylist("A", "Apple", "1KG", "24.00"). That sounds like it should be a class like "FruitPrice" or something like that.

Comment: That doesn't iterate them in parallel, though I do agree with the sentiment that a class seems appropriate.

Comment: I wasn't aware that he wants to iterate over them parallel. If he wants so, he'd have to choose another approach.

Comment: Well, two lists, one loop. Sounds like parallel iteration to me.